# Available RAM per core for mobile i7 processors

Tags: intel-core-i7, multi-core

On a i7-720QM or i7-820QM mobile processors, can each core access all of the available RAM (i.e. 8 GB out of 8 GB). I've heard that on certain desktop motherboards this can cause problems, but I can't find a source.

Answer (score 2):

Each core can access all the memory.  I'm not aware of any desktop/laptop/server that any system has that limitation.

Perhaps you are thinking of multi-socket Athlon systems where the RAM is connected to each socket, but even then each core could see all the RAM, some was just slower to access (that's called [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access) if you are interested)

Or maybe you're thinking of the 4GB limitation for 32 bit Windows XP/Vista/7?  You will need a 64bit version of Windows to access all that RAM.

Comment: I was not thinking of the 4 GB limitation for 32 bit systems. What I heard was that certain motherboards couldn't make all of the RAM available to all CPU cores (in 16+ GB systems).